# lav mic, wireless transmitter/receiver combinations

Tags: production-audio, lavalier, wireless, transmitter

I'm curious to know what combonations of equipment stated in the title are being used in larger budgeted feature productions.  Or basicly what the 'pro's in Hollywood' use when it comes to production audio on locations regarding lavalier microphones.

My biggest concern is that I don't want to purchase for example... a lav mic that has a unique end and won't fit into a certain transmitter, or needs a specific adapter for a specific type of transmitter. I really want to try and avoid any logistical oversites that may arise when using combonations of equipment that don't come in a kit.

I've done a bit of research on what lav mics are popular, and are widely used.  I've also found info on transmitter/receivers that are popular, and widely used.  I just haven't found all the info and logistics in one place.  So that's kind of what I'm looking for here.

Just to share, I'm looking at lav mics along the lines of a Tram TR50, Sanken COS-11D, or possibly even the DBA's 4061 or 4071.

As for transmitter/recievers I've heard good things about Lectrosonics series, such as UCR411 kits, and 401, and also Sennheiser 2000ENG-SK, or their G3 series.

So to reiterate, What pieces work well together, and what are the necessary tools (such as adaptors) required to make them work harmoniously?  As for the use of these, they will be primarily in production audio, but I would also use them in recording sound effects for post-production.

Pre-emptive Thanks!  expert advise is alwasy much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Lectrosonics, Zaxcom and Audio Ltd. are probably the most widely used in higher budget productions.

Unfortunately, each company pretty much has their own wiring schemes for lavalieres. It is possible to create 'jumper' cables. Like put a Sanken COS-11 wired TA5F for Lectrosonics to a Sennheiser 1/8" mini connector. Even doing that isn't ideal... but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rundown on my wireless rig, since you asked what-all it takes to make a complete system, but it is just enough to do stereo effects or a 2-person scene, like an interview: Two Lectronics 411 receivers, Lectro LMa transmitters, DPA 4060 lavs (my decision was clinched by their modular micro-dot connector and adapter system - I can plug 'em into almost anything, wireless or not), Countryman B3 lav as a backup/option (more moisture-resistant), Remote Audio MicroCat windscreens, short right-angle XLR cables to go into a recorder or mixer, Powerex AA NiMH batteries for the Tx's, iPower LiIon 9 volt batteries for the Rx's. For effects, it's actually pretty great to have a system that can follow moving sound sources without having to swing a boom accurately...

Had I the chance to do it over again, I'd have chosen the less-sensitive 4061's. They're more versatile for effects. You can even get 4062's if you're aiming to shove 'em in car engine bays and the like.